# [UIDevice cuurentDevice].orientation returning previous values in appDidBecomeActive callback

Tags: ios, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

If I take the app to background by pressing the home button, then change the device orientation and bring the app to foreground, I still get the previous device orientation value in [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation.

For example, I hold the device in Default orientation, take the app to background and rotate the device to UpsideDown orientation, then bring the app to foreground, the deviceOrientation is still Default on being queried. Only after some time, the listener for beginDeviceOrientationEvents gets called and correct value is available.

So I want to ask, where should be the first place to fetch the correct value of deviceOrientation on app relaunch?

Comment: have you tried:
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    //store the last/current orientation

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
   //get last orientation and make it your current orientation

Comment: you misunderstood the problem! i want to get the correct deviceOrientation value when app is brought to foreground. Instead of getting the current deviceOrientation, I am getting the deviceOrientation when app was sent to background.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` (as [described in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)) in your app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.

**Update**

In fact, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` might be more useful, as the value returned takes into account which orientations you have set your app to be compatible with.

Comment: Have you tried getting the value slightly later in the app's activation cycle? I've just read in Apple's [App States and Multitasking doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) that whilst suspended, notifications like those for orientation are queued, and get sent once the app becomes active again. It's possible that the orientation notification is coming _after_ `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called.

Comment: Ya, I got the correct value later in the app's cycle but i expected it to be correct at appDidBecomeActive.